# Is the only way to talk to a servlet from a JSP, an HTTP request?

Tags: java, jsp, http, servlets

I was wondering if there is some other way to pass data to the servlet from JSP or is it just an HTTP request.

HTTP request can be either a form submit or an AJAX, no any other way?

I am asking because I have a jQuery listener, and I want to get a data from the back end to the JSP after the listener is triggered, without redirection.

Should I maybe use a Scriplet? Or an Ajax?

Comment: Better tell us what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two more ways like this,

**1:** Using **jsp:forward** action. It will forward your request, not redirect.

```
<jsp:forward page="yourServletPathDeclaredInWeb_XML_file"> 
<jsp:param ... /> 
</jsp:forward>
```

**2:** Using **JSTL redirect**. It will redirect, not forward.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<c:redirect url="yourServletPathDeclaredInWeb_XML_file"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guess what you want :).

When event triggers listener on client side you should send request to server. You mentioned AJAX - yes! Use it. So you will request server side servlet (or JSP page) and when get answer, translate it to your client side content (you can get any format HTTP, XML, JSON etc). This can be done with jQuery fairly easy.

PS. Java Servlet can work not only with HTTP requests, but It looks like you not need it.